# How to trim string from right in PHP?

Tags: php, string, trim

I have a string example

```
this-is-the-example/exa
```

I want to trim /exa from the above line

```
$string1 = "this-is-the-example/exa";
$string2 = "/exa";
```

I am using `rtrim($string1, $sting2)`

But the output is `this-is-the-exampl`

I want to `this-is-the-example` as output.

Both string are dynamic and may have multiple occurrences within the string. But I only want to remove the last part. Also its not compulsory that the string2 has `/` in it. this may be normal string too. like `a`, `abc` too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various approaches you can use for this:

With `substr`([DEMO](https://eval.in/914287)):

```
function removeFromEnd($haystack, $needle)
{
    $length = strlen($needle);

    if(substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle)
    {
        $haystack = substr($haystack, 0, -$length);
    }
    return $haystack;
}


$trim = '/exa';
$str = 'this-is-the-example/exa';


var_dump(removeFromEnd($str, $trim));
```

With regex([DEMO](https://eval.in/914016)):

```
$trim = '/exa';
$str = 'this-is-the-example/exa';

function removeFromEnd($haystack, $needle)
{
    $needle = preg_quote($needle, '/');
    $haystack = preg_replace("/$needle$/", '', $haystack);
    return $haystack;
}
var_dump(removeFromEnd($str, $trim));
```

Answer (score 2):

First `explode` the string, remove last element from exploded array using `array_pop`, then `implode` it back again with `/`.

```
$str = "this-is-the-example/exa";
if(strpos($str, '/') !== false)
{
    $arr = explode('/', $str);
    array_pop($arr);
    $str = implode('/', $arr);
    // output this-is-the-example
}
```

This will work event if you have multiple `/` in the URL and will remove last element only.

```
$str = "this-is-the-example/somevalue/exa";

if(strpos($str, '/') !== false)
{
    $arr = explode('/', $str);
    array_pop($arr);
    $str = implode('/', $arr);
    // output this-is-the-example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say hi to [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$str = 'this-is-the-example/exa';
$trim = '/exa';
$result = strstr($str, $trim, true);
echo $result;
```

Comment: String may have multiple / 

or replacement string may have plain abc too.

Comment: Getting 'this-is-the-ex' as ouput when $trim = "a";

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode

```
<?php

$x = "this-is-the-example/exa";

$y = explode('/', $x);

echo $y[0];
```

Comment: "String is dynamic and may have multiple occurrences within the string" - right now, if there will be one another `/` you won't cut the last part

Comment: Ya I got your point, I was just using explode to get the desired output.

Comment: By this I can only get first part before / as ouput and what if the replacement string contain plan character like 'a'

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter of rtrim is a character mask and not a string, your last "e" is trimed and that's normal.

COnsider using something else,  regexp for example (preg_replace) to fit your needs

**This keeps everything before "/" char :**

```
$str = preg_replace('/^([^\/]*).*/','$1', 'this-is-the-example/exa');
```

**This removes the last part.**

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(.*)\/.*$/','$1', 'this-is-the-example/exa/mple');
```

Comment: It's not compulsory that I want to trim the string right from the /.

the trim string may have simple characters too. and in few cases the trim case may be empty too.

Answer (score 0):

To allow for error handling, if the substring is not found in the search string ...

```
<?php

$myString = 'this-is-the-example/exa';

//[Edit: see comment below] use strrpos, not strpos, to find the LAST occurrence 
$endPosition = strrpos($myString, '/exa');

// TodO; if endPosition === False then handle error, substring not found 

$leftPart = substr($myString, 0, $endPosition);

echo($leftPart);

?>
```

outputs

> this-is-the-example

Comment: getting 'this-is-the-ex' when I changed the trim case to 'a'.

Comment: My bad - if you use `builder()` instead of `strpos()`, it will work.  The search string 'a' is not unique . `strpos()` finds the first occurrence, while `strrpos() finds the last, which is what you want. sorry about that; I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. :)

Simply try this code:

```
<?php
$this_example = substr("this-is-the-example/exa", 0, -4);  
echo "<br/>".$this_example; // returns "this-is-the-example"
?>
```

Comment: Both the string are dynamic and the replacement might be sometimes empty in few cases. and might be plain a, abc, or anything too.